# Schirelman Theorem with even number set $E$ and its density modification

Tags: analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

[image]
[image]

---

The above one is the excerpt from a book involving sieve theory introduction. I have a question about this one. Let $E=\left\{2n : n\in\mathbb N\right\}$ be a set of all even number. The book states that the Schirelman density of set $A$, $$d(A)=\inf_{n\ge 1}\dfrac{A(n)}{n}$$ where $A(n)=\#\left\{a\le n : a\in A\right\}$. We see that $d(E)=0$ because $E(1)=0$, yet actually $d(E)>1/3$ for sufficiently large $n$ ($2$ in this case is enough). The modification above, in my opinion that I'm not sure it's true is to modify the density to be $\displaystyle d(A)=\inf_{n\ge n_0}\dfrac{A(n)}{n}$ and Corollary 6.3.3 above is then states that if (modified) $d(A)>0\Longrightarrow$ $\exists m, A^{(m)}=\mathbb{N}_{\ge n_0}$, where $\mathbb{N}_{\ge n_0}$ is the set of all sufficiently large natural number.

However, since the modified density $d(E)>0$ for $n\ge 2$ and we know it's impossible to have such $m$ in which $E^{(m)}=\mathbb{N}_{n_0}$, since the sum of even is always even and not cover the case of odds, so I don't know what these sentences are all about.

** $A^{(n)}=\left\{a_1+a_2+\dots a_n : a_i\in A\right\}\cup A$

Answer (score 1):

The passage you quote does leave some room for interpretation. Before discussing it, let's set the following notation. Given a natural number $n_0$, set $d_{n_0}(A)=\inf_{n\geq n_0}A(n)/n$.

You have interpreted the passage as follows.

> *Statement 1.* Suppose there is some natural number $n_0$ such that $d_{n_0}(A)>0$. Then there is some $m$ such that $A^{(m)}$ contains all sufficiently large natural numbers.

As you point out, the set of even numbers does refute Statement 1. However, my guess is that the author actually means the following:

> *Statement 2.* Suppose there are natural numbers $n_0$ and $k$ such that $d_{n_0}(A^{(k)})>1/2$. Then $A^{(2k)}$ contains all sufficiently large natural numbers.

So first note that the set $E$ of evens is no longer a counterexample, because $d_{n_0}(E^{(k)})\leq 1/2$ for all $n_0$. In fact, Statement 2 is true.

> *Proof of Statement 2.* We prove the general claim that if $d_{n_0}(A)>1/2$ then $A+A$ contains all natural numbers greater than $n_0$. So assume $d_{n_0}(A)>1/2$. Then $A(n)>n/2$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Now fix $n\geq n_0$. Set $X=\{a\in A:1\leq a\leq n\}$ and $Y=\{n+1-a:a\in X\}$. Then $X$ and $Y$ are subsets of $[1,n]$ of size $A(n)>n/2$. So $X$ and $Y$ intersect, i.e., $n+1-a=b$ for some $a,b\in A$, i.e., $n+1\in A+A$.

Now the natural question is how close we can get to something like Statement 1. One option is the following.

**Theorem.** Let $r=gcd(A)$ and assume $d_{n_0}(A)>0$ for some $n_0$. Then there is some $k$ such that $A^{(k)}$ contains all sufficiently large multiples of $r$.

Note that since every element of $A$ is a multiple of $r$, this is optimal.

The previous theorem is a consequence of Lemma 1 of *Cofinite subsets of asymptotic bases for the positive integers*, J. Number Theory 1985 by John C. M. Nash and Melvyn B. Nathanson. The proof sketch is as follows. Without loss of generality, you can replace $A$ by $\{a/r:a\in A\}$ and thus assume $r=1$. Let $B=A\cup\{1\}$. Then $d_{n_0}(A)>0$ implies $d(B)>0$ (this part doesn't use $r=1$). So by Corollary 6.3.3 there is some $m$ such that $B^{(m)}=\mathbb{N}$. Then there are some tricks using the assumption $gcd(A)=1$ to get from $B^{(m)}=\mathbb{N}$ to $A^{(k)}$ containing sufficiently large natural numbers for some $k$.